# how to get categories values and spacing in label in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

what i am trying to get is below, [image: Output image]

but my output is,[image]

my code is below,

```
function aoassortmentschart() {
$(function () {
    $('#ao-assortments-container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            inverted : true
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        title: null,
        subtitle : null,
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Cluster 5", "Cluster 4", "Cluster 3", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 1"],
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter : function() {
                    return '<div style="margin-left: 120px,width: 100px;"><input type="radio"  style="margin-right: 100px"/>' + this.categories + '</div>';
                }
            },
            tickWidth: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 250,

            title: {
                useHTML : true,
                formatter: function(){
                    return '<div class="ao-assortment-title"><span class="shape" style="width: 40px;height:40px;bacground:green">&nbsp;</span>Sales</div>'
                }
            }

        },
        legend : {
            enabled: false,

        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                paddingLeft: "50px",
                pointInterval : 50,

                dataLabels: {
                    align: 'top',
                    verticalAlign : "middle",
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return "$ " + this.y
                },
                style: {
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: "#000"
                }

            }
            },
            styles : {
                minHeight : "200px"
            },

        },
        series: [
        {
            name : "5 clusters",
            data: [198],
            color: "#60B3D1"
        },
        {
            name: "4 clusters",
            data: [71.5],
            color: "#60B3D1"
        },
        {
            name: "3 clusters",
            data: [21.5],
            color: "#60B3D1"
        },
        {
            name: "2 clusters",
            data: [31.5],
            color: "#60B3D1"
        },
        {
            name: "1 clusters",
            data: [51.5],
            color: "#60B3D1"
        }
        ]
    });
    // the button action

}); }
```

so,

- how can i achieve the clusters value column
- and spacing of the plotting bars from y axis?

help would be appreciated!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set x value for each point and disable `grouping` for series to get chart similar to your requirements. In xAxis formatter to get coategory use `this.value`.

Example #1: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzrje8fn/

Knowing that x can be set for point, you can set all points in a single series and set `keys` for points.

Example #2: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzrje8fn/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy fix. Instead of using `this.categories` in your xAxis label formatter, use `this.value`.

Whenever you use the "formatter" function, your calls are self-referential (in this case, "this" = the categories you're formatting).

I hope this helps!